# regex | how to add prefix to a matched substring?

Tags: regex

Suppose I have the follow files:

```
../dir
   |__ attention.md
   |__ attention.percent.20.pt.md
   |__ attention.percent.60.st.md
   |__ attention.reserved.md
```

I want to add a `[tag]` to any files whose names contain `percent`, but apparently the code below replaces an entire prefix up to and including `percent`.

```
$ rename -n 's/(\w+\.)*(percent)(\w+\.)*/[tag]/' *.md

rename(attention.percent.20.pt.md, [tag].20.pt.md)
rename(attention.percent.60.st.md, [tag].60.st.md)
```

---

**I should clarify my question:**

I want to add `[tag]` to the beginning of any string that contains `percent` anywhere in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `$&` in replacement:

```sh
rename -n 's/(\w+\.)*percent(\w+\.)*/[tag]$&/' *.md
'attention.percent.20.pt.md' would be renamed to '[tag]attention.percent.20.pt.md'
```

`$&` is back-reference for complete matched text.

**Alternatively** you can just put your pattern in a lookahead as well:

```sh
rename -n 's/(?=(\w+\.)*percent)/[tag]/' *.md
'attention.percent.20.pt.md' would be renamed to '[tag]attention.percent.20.pt.md'
```

Comment: Thank you, this actually solved a previously question I had. However, what I want to ask for this question is to add a prefix to the entire filename, i.e. `[tag][filename].md`. Is there a way to do that?